# Realm: Is Migration Needed?

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

Is there a way to ask Realm in Android if migration is needed?

I have my configuration in place so that realm gets deleted if migration is needed.

```
realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration
        .Builder(context)
        .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
        .build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
```

This is fine for my purpose, but I need to know when this happens, because I need to store default data into the database if it has been erased.
Any tips how I can react to realm deleting the data?

Comment: Migration is needed when you (manually) change the database scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [initialData](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.Builder.html#initialData-io.realm.Realm.Transaction-) method to which you can provide an initial transaction that sets up your data - it runs if the Realm is empty, or if `deleteIfMigrationNeeded()` deleted your Realm.